# LWC buttons are not visible in Salesforce mobile app

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, button, lightning-development

Is there a way to make LWC actions visible in mobile app? The LWC actions which are visible for desktop are not visible in mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_web_component_actions_create.htm&type=5), Lightning Web Component quick actions are available only on record pages in Lightning Experience. They’re not supported on the Salesforce mobile app.

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000H6s0TUAR/enable-lightning-web-componentlwc-in-salesforce-mobile-app) and vote.

Answer (score 1):

As observed by Alok Kumar at ideaexchange (reference below), there is a workaround for this. You may create a Custom Link or Custom Button and call your LWC via quick action on mobile.

> Work Around :
> Use New Button or link and set the below url
>
> {domain_url}/lightning/action/quick/{objectApiname}.{Api_name_of_the_quick_action}?context=RECORD_DETAIL&recordId={!CASESAFEID(
> {objectApiname}.Id )}
>
> e.g.
> https://testdomain.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/action/quick/Lead.DB_Enrichment?context=RECORD_DETAIL&recordId={!CASESAFEID(
> Lead.Id )}

Complementing Alok Kumar, you actually don't need to use the domain and if you use following model, it will also work, without having to worry about the org's domain between deployments:

```
/lightning/action/quick/{objectApiname}.{Api_name_of_the_quick_action}?context=RECORD_DETAIL&recordId={!CASESAFEID( {objectApiname}.Id )}
```

After creating it, you can add the button/link on your Lightning Page or Page Layout and it will work perfectly.

If you do add it to a Lightning Page (mobile version),please remember to activate "Enable page-level actions for the Salesforce mobile app" configuration on Lightning Page in order to be able to select created button.

You may upvote an improvement for LWC to be allowed on mobile apps at ideaexchange. Please, see references.

---

Reference:

1. https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000H6s0TUAR/enable-lightning-web-componentlwc-in-salesforce-mobile-app

Answer (score 0):

Host LWC component inside a flow and then use the flow as the button. Now the button will be available on Mobile App as well.